# Unable to access Azure blob in LocalStorage via its URL

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating a Web Application as part of an assignment I have. The task is to upload an audio clip to an ASP page and then a Web Job will then generate from it  a 20 second sample which is then displayed on the same page. I will eventually need to deploy it to Azure but at the moment I'm using local storage with the Azure Storage Emulator.

The page loads correctly and the audio is uploading to the Blob Container okay and the samples are being generated and placed in the correct folder. However the samples aren't loading into the player and I'm not able to access these samples through the browser, even when using the URL I'm reading right off the blobs in storage.

[image: Blobs in Local Storage]

When I enter that URL into the browser (with the Application and Web Job both running)  I get this message displayed:

[image: Resource Not Found]

My first instinct was that I didn't have the necessary permissions to access the container. However as far as I can tell the permissions have been configured correctly. Below is my BlobStorageService class that handles the permissions for the containers:

```
namespace Sampler
{
    public class BlobStorageService
    {
        public CloudBlobContainer getCloudBlobContainer()
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse
                (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureStorage"].ToString());

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("audiostorage");

            if (container.CreateIfNotExists())
            {
                BlobContainerPermissions permissions = container.GetPermissions();
                permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;
                container.SetPermissions(permissions);
            }
            return container;
        }
    }
```

So as far as I can tell the permissions should be Public for the whole container and the code I used for it came directly from Microsoft Docs. Any suggestions for next course of action greatly appreciated and happy to post any more code you might need to see.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but are the web application and emulator running on the same machine as the browser that you're using to access the app?

Comment: JLRishe - Yes they're all running locally on the same machine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is logic issue in your code. If the container is existed, then  the permisson of the container will not be public, default is private. If we try to list the blob in the private container, will get not found issue. Please have a try to use the following code. Or we could use the [Microsoft Azure Storage Exploer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to set the container public and try it again.

```
 public CloudBlobContainer getCloudBlobContainer()
  {
      CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureStorage"].ToString());
      CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
      CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("audiostorage");
      container.CreateIfNotExists(); // remove the if condition
      BlobContainerPermissions permissions = container.GetPermissions();
      permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;
      container.SetPermissions(permissions);  
      return container;
   }
```